# Systemd/rsyslog logging not working as expected

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, rsyslog, tomcat

I've got a fairly vanilla Ubuntu 20.04LTS box where I've deployed Tomcat9 from repo. Out of the box, this appears to be configured to write its logs to /var/log/tomcat9/ and there are indeed log files there. However these only have a small fraction of the information I was expecting - the remainder is visible in the output of `systemctl status tomcat9` and is being written to /var/log/syslog.

The only relevant thing in the supplied unit file is.....

```
SyslogIdentifier=tomcat9
```

While the installation of tomcat also created /etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat9.conf containing....

```
# Send Tomcat messages to catalina.out when using systemd
$template TomcatFormat,"[%timegenerated:::date-year%-%timegenerated:::date-month%-%timegenerated:::date-day% %timegenerated:::date-hour%:%timegenerated:::date-minute%:%timegenerated:::date-second%] [%syslogseverity-text%]%msg%\n"

:programname, startswith, "tomcat9" {
  /var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out;TomcatFormat
  stop
}
```

An example of the output of `systemctl status tomcat9`

```
● tomcat9.service - Apache Tomcat 9 Web Application Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat9.service.d
             └─override.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-04-08 13:07:39 UTC; 17min ago
       Docs: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html
    Process: 1006 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/tomcat9/tomcat-update-policy.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1026 (java)
      Tasks: 53 (limit: 2274)
     Memory: 332.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat9.service
             └─1026 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.C>

Apr 08 13:20:14 myhost.example.com tomcat9[1026]: [cfPullService] DEBUG 13:20:14 ConnectionManager.openConnection(444) | opening JDBC connection
Apr 08 13:20:14 myhost.example.com tomcat9[1026]: [cfPullService] DEBUG 13:20:14 JDBCTransaction.begin(87) | current autocommit status: true
Apr 08 13:20:14 myhost.example.com tomcat9[1026]: [cfPullService] DEBUG 13:20:14 JDBCTransaction.begin(90) | disabling autocommit
Apr 08 13:20:14 myhost.example.com tomcat9[1026]: [cfPullService] DEBUG 13:20:14 JDBCTransaction.commit(134) | commit
Apr 08 13:20:14 myhost.example.com tomcat9[1026]: [cfPullService] DEBUG 13:20:14 JDBCTransaction.toggleAutoCommit(227) | re-enabling autocommit
```

The "cfPullService" above is coming from the deployed java code (which is effectively a black box) and may contain other values at other times.

And example of the entries in /var/log/syslog...

```
Apr  8 13:20:12 myhost tomcat9[1026]: [cfPullService] INFO 13:20:12 RunSearchManagerImpl.runEarlyEngagementSearch(165) | Finished saving early engagement notices.
Apr  8 13:20:12 myhost tomcat9[1026]: [cfPullService] INFO 13:20:12 RunSearchManagerImpl.runPipelineSearch(176) | Running pipeline search
```

The supplied /etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat9.conf looks like this:

```
# Send Tomcat messages to catalina.out when using systemd
$template TomcatFormat,"[%timegenerated:::date-year%-%timegenerated:::date-month%-%timegenerated:::date-day% %timegenerated:::date-hour%:%timegenerated:::date-minute%:%timegenerated:::date-second%] [%syslogseverity-text%]%msg%\n"

:programname, startswith, "tomcat9" {
  /var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out;TomcatFormat
  stop
}
```

I tried creating a systemd override file (and applied a daemon reload) with....

```
[Service]
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
```

but this had no impact on the behaviour.

How do I

1. get the output of tomcat to go a file in /var/log/tomcat9
2. stop sending the output of tomcat to /var/log/syslog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that part of the issue is described in [bug #1861881](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat9/+bug/1861881).

I was able to get a working log file while excluding the entries from syslog by:

1. removing the content from /etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat.conf (leaving blank file to prevent reinstatement by auto patching)
2. putting the content in /etc/rsyslog.d/12-tomcat9.conf (to ensure it was loaded before 50-default.conf) and avoid "action 'action-11-builtin:omfile' suspended (module 'builtin:omfile'), retry 0. There should be messages before this one giving the reason for"
3. amending the path from /var/log/tomcat9/catalina.out to /var/log/tomcat.log to avoid the permissions issue (/var/log/tomcat9 is not writeable by the syslog user)
4. adding a new /etc/logrotate.d file with content below....

```
/var/log/tomcat.log
{
        rotate 7
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                /usr/lib/rsyslog/rsyslog-rotate
        endscript
}
```